# How should be installed and configured SQL Server 2012 Apache Web Server 2,4 and PHP 7 for working together?

Tags: php, apache, configuration, sql-server-2012, wamp

Instead of the common WAMP configuration with MySQL DBMS I would like to use Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

I have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I downloaded the targz [Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi#apache24) file and [PHP zip](http://windows.php.net/download/) (or is better [PHP installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpinstallermsi/)?).

I put the targz content in `C:\apache` and the same for PHP in `C:\php`.
I have also installed [this driver for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.web-site-scripts.com/knowledge-base/article/AA-00748/0/PHP-drivers-for-Microsoft-SQL-Windows-Apache.html).

I have found [this guide](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/php/sql_server_unix_tutorial.html) but it is for Linux.

Do you know, step by step, how I can configure this environment? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, how have you tried to configure it? For instance, can you demonstrate that PHP is working on your command line? Is the SQL server demonstrably running? What about Apache? Where are you running into an error trying to connect these resources?

Comment: If you dont know how to configure all these part together then why not use WAMPServer or XAMPP. Then it is all done at the click of an installer. Then your only issue will be SQLServer. I have a feeling that the current php_mssql.dll is only available in 32, so install the 32bit version of WAMPSever or XAMPP.

Comment: I tried WAMP and XAMPP but  i got a generic error if i open the C:/xampp/htdocs/index.php file :something is wrong with XAMPP installation or a white page at localhost. in the Xampp control panel apache is green labelled after that i changed the 80 port to 8079

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is currently no stable MSSQL Driver for PHP 7. There is one in development, although they will most likely wait until the Release of MSSQL 2016 to be compatible.

The driver for PHP 5.6 is available here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

And here are some informations about the driver release for PHP 7: https://github.com/Azure/msphpsql/issues/58

Comment: Note:  
meet-bhagdev commented 5 days ago
Still working on it very very hard. Expect to see something from us by the end of the month.